# How do I add the following key bindings to my Emacs startup script?

Tags: key-bindings, clojure

I'm learning Clojure.

Every day, I open up Emacs and key in the following commands:

```
C-x 3 ; create a new window on the right
M-x cider-jack-in ; open up a REPL
C-x o ; switch to my left window
C-x C-f code/clojure-projects/something.clj ; open up a file and start coding
```

I would like to automate these, so that they automatically happen every time Emacs starts.

To do this, I need to add something to the bottom of my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file, right?

I would also like to know the process by which I can figure out how to do these things in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please do not cross-post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673177/how-do-i-add-the-following-key-bindings-to-my-emacs-init-el) on Stack Overflow at the same time.  Please pick one or the other.

Comment: @Dan Thanks! And why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `global-set-key` to create or change a global key binding.
- Use `define-key` to create or change a local (mode-specific) key binding, that is, a binding in a particular keymap.

Use the *Emacs manual* to find out about these things: **`C-h r`**.

In the manual, use **`i`** to look something up in the index, using completion. For example, `i key bindings` (or `i key bind TAB` to complete).

That takes you to node (page) [Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) of the manual, where you see a "menu" (table of contents) that includes this entry, which is the node you want to visit:

```
* Init Rebinding  Rebinding keys with your initialization file.
```

Just click the link `Init Rebinding` to go to that node. There you'll find a complete description of how to bind keys in your init file, including examples.

For a specific mode or keymap, such as Clojure mode likely uses, check the doc for the mode to see what keymap(s) it uses.  If you can't discover the map(s) that way, try the mode name (e.g. `clojure-mode`?) followed by `-map`: `clojure-mode-map`.  Use `define-key` to define a key binding in that keymap.